# PDF to XML Conversion

Tags: java, xml, pdf, adobe, enterprise

We are looking for an enterprise solution that can convert a PDF document to XML data.

I am ok with any solutions;

1. if there is an off the shelf product from a major software provider.
2. Is there a Java framework that we can use?
3. Is there a API that adobe provides?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Tika to read pdf document contents and then transform that to XML in some way. Maybe create a Apache Camel route that reads documents in a folder then use Tika to extract content and then spit that out as XML somewhere else.